# Accessing om.next sub-component state

Tags: om, om.next

I'm just picking up om.next and have run into a situation where I've got some form inputs realized as components which hold on to local state, e.g. validation state, actual input value, etc--this state is updated and accessed via `om.next/update-state!` and `om.next/get-state`. The trouble with this seems to be when I wrap the inputs in a form in a parent component I'm unsure how to get the state held by the input components. Is it better to pass along the parent component as a property of the input component? What about situations where there is no parent component?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that there are 2 options for the use case you want to achieve:

1. pass the parent component as an argument as you said
2. have an entry in the global app-state that represents the current form being edited, which you can update via `transact!` irregardless of the component corresponding to the input. This way every component that represents an input knows where in the app-state to update itself (which key in the current form) — probably captured succintly in one mutation function.

1) is probably the easiest to implement given the code you have currently, but I always like to go for 2) because it doesn't deviate from the "single source of truth" opinion that Om Next recommends (and tries to enforce). Form data is in fact business data, which might not be desirable to have scattered in components. Testability is just one advantage that I immediately see from such approach.